# perspective projection of line segments

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, geometry, perspective

when i cast 3d point on 2d screen i use

```
    if( z > 1.0 )                   
     {
      screen_x = (x/z)*500;         
      screen_y = (y/z)*500;
     }
```

this is i just can throw away all 'rear' points and
scale front points

but now i need to cast/projects line segments - to
2d points then i can draw it as 2d line

some cases would be that one point of line segment is 
in front space but the other in rear space - how to cast
the rear space point so I could draw it as a 2d line?

much tnx for answer

Comment: Do you want the line to be straight on the screen?

Comment: what do you mean stright on the screen? I want to do 3d made from lines, wires - with perspectivical projection

Comment: You want to project a 3D line segment into 2D. You want to project widely separated points at high z to points that are close together. Do you have any other requirements? Like maybe you want line segments to map to line segments? I ask because I don't want to submit an answer and then find out that it wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: do not understand this question - I just want to projest 3d line segment (x,y,z)-(x2,y2,z2) to 2d line segment (x,y)-(x2,y2) i could draw on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you ask:

```
screen_x = (x/(|z|+1.0))*500;         
screen_y = (y/(|z|+1.0))*500;
```

Comment: well, great if it will work, i am not sure, must check.. and no if(z>something) or something like that?